# Can't set different colors for each bar when I put it on top of a clustergram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is my example, I can't get different bar colors defined.... for some reason all are red.
[image: That's what I get]

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
# initiliaze a dataframe with index and column names 
idf = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6]), ('C', 10, 
20, 30]), ('D', [14, 15, 16])], orient='index', columns=['x', > 'y', 'z'])
# Plot the clustermap which will be a figure by itself 
cax = sns.clustermap(idf, col_cluster=False, row_cluster=True)

# Get the column dendrogram axis 
cax_col_dend_ax = cax.ax_col_dendrogram.axes
# Plot the boxplot on the column dendrogram axis
idf.iloc[0,:].plot(kind='bar', ax=cax_col_dend_ax, color = ['r', 'g', 'b'])

# Show the plot 
plt.show()
```

Comment: It works fine for me using matplotlib version `'2.2.2'`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. It seems you are using old python version because I got a `FutureWarning: from_items is deprecated.`. Although this is from `pandas` but you might want to upgrade. Nevertheless, you can still change the colors as follows

```
import matplotlib as mpl

# Your code here
ax1 = idf.iloc[0,:].plot.bar(ax=cax_col_dend_ax)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
bars = [r for r in ax1.get_children() if isinstance(r, mpl.patches.Rectangle)]

for i, bar in enumerate(bars[0:3]):
    bar.set_color(colors[i])
```

[image]